# jQuery, $.each how to prevent table from going to next row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have json data that needs to be displayed in a table,  I have two $.each loops to create a table. However, jquery creates a new row for the inner $.each loop.  How can i prevent the outer $.each from appending a new row? I have created a JSfiddle for it.

```
$.each(data,function(row,val){
    $('#responsetable tbody:last').append("<tr></tr><td>" +val.anno+ "</td><td>"+ val.descrizione.descrizione + "</td>" );

    $.each(val.dir_empty,function(key,value){

        $('#responsetable tbody').append("<td>"+value+"</td>");


    });
});
```

[jsfiffle tabular data](http://jsfiddle.net/bretuobay/z4m75pkg/)

Comment: You're appending TD elements to the `tbody` directly, which is invalid, so the browser, not jQuery, tries to fix your mistake and creates TR elements for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9sfhhL4u/ might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your each method to the following:

```
$.each(data,function(row,val) {
    var toAppend = "<tr><td>" +val.anno+ "</td><td>"+ val.descrizione.descrizione + "</td>";

    $.each(val.dir_empty,function(key,value){
        toAppend += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
    });

    toAppend += "</tr>";

    $('#responsetable tbody').append(toAppend);
});
```

Essentially only creating one row for each outer iteration.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4m75pkg/4/)

Comment: please edit your answer with the closing brackets and parentheses on the first line so i can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Edited, was a copy paste issue, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the inner each's tds to be 'inside' the outer each's tr? Cause right now you add them to the body with no row.

I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but maybe this does it?

```
$.each(data,function(row,val){
    $('#responsetable tbody:last').append("<tr><td>" +val.anno+ "</td><td>"+ val.descrizione.descrizione + "</td></tr>" );

    $.each(val.dir_empty,function(key,value){

        $('#responsetable tbody tr:last').append("<td>"+value+"</td>");


    });
});
```

Comment: The table row isn't actually wrapping all of the cells in the row here. You will see in the dev tools that you have an empty <tr /> before each <tr /> that contains data.

Comment: Oh, you are right. The way the tr is appended in the first loop threw me off. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$.each(data,function(row,val){
    $('#responsetable tbody').append("<tr>");
    $('#responsetable tbody').append("<td>" +val.anno+ "</td><td>"+ val.descrizione.descrizione + "</td>" );
    $.each(val.dir_empty,function(key,value){
        $('#responsetable tbody').append("<td>"+value+"</td>");
    });
    $('#responsetable tbody').append("</tr>");
})
```